# react native with zustand persist

Tags: javascript, react-native, zustand

I'm trying to implement a simple todo app with react-native and zustand persist, the code without the `persist` method is working fine, but when I try to introduce persist, I run into errors or I'm not able to correctly implement it, I went through the documentation on zustand page, but it is not working. Below is the relevant code and errors:

App.tsx

```js
const App = () => {
  const { todos, addTodo, getTodos } = useTodoStore((state: TodoState) => state);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    getTodos();
  }, []);

  return (
    ...
  )
}
```

zustand store:

```js
import create from 'zustand';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';
import AsynStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

export interface Todo {
  id: string;
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
  createdAt: string;
}

export interface TodoState {
  todos: Todo[];
  addTodo: (todo: Todo) => void;
  getTodos: () => void;
  removeTodo: (id: string) => void;
  toggleTodo: (id: string) => void;
}

export const useTodoStore = create<TodoState>(
  // @ts-ignore
  persist(
    set => ({
      todos: [],
      getTodos: () => {
        AsynStorage.getItem('todo-storage').then(todos => {
          if (todos) {
            set(state => ({ ...state, todos: JSON.parse(todos) }));
          }
        });
      },
      addTodo: (todo: Todo) => {
      set(state => {
        console.log('state: ', state.todos);
        return {
          ...state,
          todos: [...state.todos, todo],
          };
        });
      },
      removeTodo: (id: string) => {
        set(state => ({
          ...state,
          todos: state.todos.filter(todo => todo.id !== id),
        }));
      },
      toggleTodo: (id: string) => {
        set(state => ({
          ...state,
          todos: state.todos.map(todo =>
            todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo,
          ),
        }));
      },
    }),
    {
      name: 'todo-storage',
      getStorage: () => AsynStorage,  
    },
  ),
);
```

Now, when I try to add a todo, I run into the following error:

```
ERROR  TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance.
In order to be iterable, non-array objects must have a [Symbol.iterator]() method.
```

So, does anyone have a code example with persist (react-native), I don't understand what I'm doing wrong here, I'm doing as shown in docs.

**EDIT**:
If I remove `persist` middleware and all code related to it, it works just fine, also, to note:

When I use `persist` middleware with `async-storage`, the state is this:

```
LOG  state:  {"state": {"_hasHydrated": true, "todos": {"state": [Object], "version": 0}}, "version": 0}
```

And when I don't use `persist` it works:

```
LOG  state:  [{"completed": false, "createdAt": "Fri Jul 22 2022 14:27:47 GMT+0530 (IST)", "id": "6bfdab5e34b198", "text": "Let’s seeeee"}]
```

Comment: Have you considered using something like mmkv instead? It's synchronous, as opposed to AsyncStorage, and not to mention faster. Check out this gist:
https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-mmkv/blob/master/docs/WRAPPER_ZUSTAND_PERSIST_MIDDLEWARE.md

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how zustand handles storages other than the default ones on the web, but I'm assuming perhaps the API doesn't match with the react-native-async-storage. I would suggest you implement the get and set methods of your storage manually like they have explained in the docs here: https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/integrations/persisting-store-data.md#how-can-i-use-a-custom-storage-engine

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried running your code yet. However, you don't need to manually call `AsyncStorage.getItem()` to restore the saved store. The `persist` middleware handles that. `getTodos`, which I suspect is the errant action, is therefore unnecessary. I further suspect that zustand `persist` adds extra metadata to the serialized data, which is what you see when you manually log it out.

See [this example](https://gist.github.com/aphilas/e3e159f8a223706291658081c6f3177f) on the general structure (actions elided).